# Add .txt extension in JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have a method that get text from a JTextArea, create a file and write text on it as code below:

```
public void createTxt() {

    TxtFilter txt = new TxtFilter();

    JFileChooser fSave = new JFileChooser();

    fSave.setFileFilter(txt);
    int result = fSave.showSaveDialog(this);
    if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File sFile = fSave.getSelectedFile();
        FileFilter selectedFilter = fSave.getFileFilter();

        String file_name = sFile.getName();
        String file_path = sFile.getParent();

        try{
            if(!sFile.exists()) {
                sFile.createNewFile();
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sFile));
                out.write(jTextArea1.getText());
                out.close();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Warning file • " + file_name + " • created succesfully in \n" + file_path);    
            } else {
                String message = "File • " + file_name + " • already exist in \n" + file_path + ":\n" + "Do you want to overwrite?";
                String title = "Warning";
                int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, title, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if(reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                    sFile.delete();
                    sFile.createNewFile();
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sFile));
                    out.write(jTextArea1.getText());
                    out.close();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File • " + file_name + " • overwritten succesfully in \n" + file_path);

                }
            }
        }
       catch(IOException e) {
           System.out.println("Error");
       }
    }
}
```

and a txt file filter

```
public class TxtFilter extends FileFilter{
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File f){
        return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")||f.isDirectory();
    }
    @Override
    public String getDescription(){
        return "Text files (*.txt)";
    }
}
```

The file filter for txt works fine but what I want is to add ".txt" extension when I type file name.

How to I have to modify my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You pointed me out that the check for existing files doesn't work. I'm sorry, I didn't think of it when I suggested you to replace the `BufferedWriter` line.
Now, replace this:

```
File sFile = fSave.getSelectedFile();
```

with:

```
File sFile = new File(fSave.getSelectedFile()+".txt");
```

With this replacement, it isn't now needed to replace the line of `BufferedWriter`, adding `.txt` for the extension. Then, replace that line with the line in the code you posted (with `BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sFile));` instead of `BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sFile+".txt"));`).

Now the program should work as expected.

I forgot to mention that you have to comment the line:

```
sFile.createNewFile();
```

In this way, you're creating an empty file, with the class `File`.

Just after this line, there is: `BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sFile));`. 
With this line, you are creating again the same file. The writing procedure is happening two times! I think it's useless to insert two instructions that are doing the same task.

Also, on the `BufferedWriter` constructor, you can append a string for the file name (it isn't possible on `File` constructor), that's the reason why I added `+".txt"` (the extension) to `sFile`.

Comment: Very strange! On my system everything works..I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful infos!
You are right I did wrote twice the file, there is no reason for this.
Now files are correctly saved with suffix ".txt

Comment: There is only one little question still left: I can now save automatically with .txt extension, but I haven't .txt in FileChooser description name.
This means that when I save again with a previous file name, it never prompt me file already exist and always overwrite the previous file
Example: let's suppose I want to save a file as name = test: now it save as test.txt and create such file. If I want to save another file with the same name, it doesn't get test file as already written since the one saved is now test.txt

Comment: @Albertoacepsut I understood. But you've replaced the string I suggested to you with "BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sFile+".txt"));" and comment the line "sFile.createNewFile();" also in the 'else' loop?

Comment: Yes I did, but the problem is that in this way it never found an already existing file so it never ask for overwrite.

Comment: No problem, forgive me because I didn't thought first about the checking if the file exists.

Answer (score 18):

I just use this

```
File fileToBeSaved = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

if(!fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath().endsWith(suffix)){
    fileToBeSaved = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile() + suffix);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a utility function from one of my programs that you can use instead of `JFileChooser.getSelectedFile`, to get the extension too.

```
/**
 * Returns the selected file from a JFileChooser, including the extension from
 * the file filter.
 */
public static File getSelectedFileWithExtension(JFileChooser c) {
    File file = c.getSelectedFile();
    if (c.getFileFilter() instanceof FileNameExtensionFilter) {
        String[] exts = ((FileNameExtensionFilter)c.getFileFilter()).getExtensions();
        String nameLower = file.getName().toLowerCase();
        for (String ext : exts) { // check if it already has a valid extension
            if (nameLower.endsWith('.' + ext.toLowerCase())) {
                return file; // if yes, return as-is
            }
        }
        // if not, append the first extension from the selected filter
        file = new File(file.toString() + '.' + exts[0]);
    }
    return file;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this function for this purpose :

```
/**
 * Add extension to a file that doesn't have yet an extension
 * this method is useful to automatically add an extension in the savefileDialog control
 * @param file file to check
 * @param ext extension to add
 * @return file with extension (e.g. 'test.doc')
 */
private String addFileExtIfNecessary(String file,String ext) {
    if(file.lastIndexOf('.') == -1)
        file += ext;

    return file;
}
```

Then you can use the function for example in this way :

```
JFileChooser fS = new JFileChooser();
String fileExt = ".txt";
addFileExtIfNecessary(fS.getSelectedFile().getName(),fileExt)
```

Comment: thanks but I have Exception 
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at provegrafica.ProvaFramePop.createTxt(ProvaFramePop.java:145)

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if the filename contains "."?